# I have 10 files of 500MB to upload, What is the best solution for this issue

Tags: php, file-upload, slim

I am using Slim Framework to upload files. I need to upload 10 files in single request of 500MB size. How can I accomplish this. I am using following code for this.

```
$uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles(); 
 foreach ($uploadedFiles['aws_file'] as $uploadedFile) {
              if ($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {  
                  $uploadFileName = $uploadedFile->getClientFilename();  
                  $fileDetails = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientFileName()); 
                  $fileName = explode('_',$fileDetails['filename']);                     
                  if(count($fileName)==3) {
                      $orgIdArray[] = $fileName[1];   
                  }           
              } else {
                  $responseObj->status = 'error';
                  $responseObj->message = 'Error in file or file is empty ';
                  $responseObj->errorFileList[] = $uploadedFile->getError();                                     
              }  
          }
```

I am getting memory issue.

Comment: You can use ftp protocol

Comment: Are you taking about ftp client like- Filezila or code in php? I want do it from code can you provide me any reference it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your [`memory_limit`](https://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) PHP setting.